# invalid characters not visible in BASH

Tags: bash, ssh, character-encoding, telnet, invalid-characters

I have been working on some device that allowed login via telnet and I extracted some data from devices and made some reports, without any problems. recently, I had to switch to SSH while rest of the script is all the same, only login procedure has been changed from telnet to SSH. after switching to SSH, I am facing some problem with the data extracted that there are some invalid characters in some of the lines, below is an example: as can be seen, there is an invalid character after PON7 in the line:

```
OLT:LT6.PON7.ONT1,ALARM,Date time,
```

problem is that this invalid character is not even visible in the bash/csv file, but it was discovered when I copied the line in notepad++ or while posting it here.

now I have two problems: 
1st: if someone knows what is causing these invalid characters while switching between telnet/ssh. 
2nd: how to deal with this invalid character in BASH as it is not even visible in BASH, but this report is being used somewhere and these invalid characters are causing problems.

Edit:

Pasting the text into a [text-to-hex converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html) produces this:

```
4f 4c 54 3a 4c 54 36 2e 50 4f 4e 37 11 2e 4f 4e 54 31 2c 41 4c 41 52 4d 2c 44 61 74 65 20 74 69 6d 65 2c
```

It looks like there's a DC1 character (hex 11) between the "7" and the ".".

Unfortunately, this edit also has the side effect of removing the character from the sample text.

Comment: the invalid character was visible while posting here but after I posted the question, it is not visible anymore. How can I share the actual text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing your text through a [text to hexadecimal converter](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/) shows that the invisible character is an [ASCII DC1 character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Device_control) (hex 11, octal 021). This character is also known as Ctrl-Q or XON. It's sometimes used in flow control.

In a bash script, you could filter it out using the `tr` program:

```
echo $badtext | tr -d '\021'
```

SSH doesn't inherently insert DC1 characters into text streams. If you're getting a DC1 character in the output from a device, presumably the device sent that character.

Comment: yes, there is DC1 Character and it seems the device itself is sending that character, but the problem is I only need to filter that character from the output while keeping the whole line intact, I will try to use sed to work around this problem, if you can suggest something, please do

Comment: If you want help adding the filter to your existing script, you should include the relevant part of your existing script in your question.

Comment: I think your above comment would be sufficient, I have echoed the text and translated it as you suggested, with next report, I will validate this. actually these devices are using TL1 language, (a typical language for Telecom Equipment) and possibly this DC1 character was there all along, but not sure why it didn't make any problems while using telnet.

Comment: below is the part of code, where I added the translation as you suggested, but still I am seeing the DC1 character in the output.

`echo "$ONTID,$ALM,$COMBDate,$INVDATA" | tr -d '\017'`

Comment: I misread the [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/). It should be `... | tr -d '\021'`

Comment: Is there a way to delete this and all invalid characters from native files? I mean before doing rest of the processing on the file, I would want to remove these characters, or if there is a way to block these characters from being stored in the file in the first place... I can share my script structure that I use to login and extract data from devices, if required,